# SQL Server Nested Case when within select

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below case is currently part of a select query. Essentially it says if FreeStockQuantity is 0 then use the value from another field unless that is 0 or null. It then returns the result as 'Quantity'

```sql
CASE WHEN FreeStockQuantity <= 0 AND (AnalysisCode19 > 0 OR AnalysisCode19 is NOT NULL) THEN AnalysisCode19
ELSE FreeStockQuantity
END AS Quantity,
```

I need to somehow nest that within a case that says when the result is > 30 THEN 30.

What is the best way to do this? Ideally, I'd like to keep that ELSE in there for any unexpected results which is why I want to nest it within another case.

Comment: I can't guarantee that AnalysisCode19 is always going to be a number (someone could mistype a letter in) which would cause the script to error

Comment: @dnoeth `AnalysisCode19 is NOT NULL` covers the case of `AnalysisCode19 > 0` and not he other way around.

Comment: @Josh Checking for a non-NULL value will not prevent this. You should TRYCAST then.

Comment: @dnoeth If `AnalysisCode19 = -1` then `AnalysisCode19 > 0 OR AnalysisCode19 is NOT NULL` returns TRUE. If the OP removes `OR AnalysisCode19 is NOT NULL` it will return FALSE.

Comment: @forpas Correct, of course. Then it's the same as `CASE WHEN FreeStockQuantity <= 0 AND AnalysisCode19 is NOT NULL THEN AnalysisCode19`
 Stupid conditions seem to confuse me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CASE WHEN FreeStockQuantity <= 0 AND (AnalysisCode19 > 0 OR AnalysisCode19 is NOT NULL) THEN
  case when AnalysisCode19 > 30 then 30 else AnalysisCode19 end
ELSE
  case when FreeStockQuantity > 30 then 30 else FreeStockQuantity end
END
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need the `NOT NULL` comparison, so you can simplify the logic to:

```
(CASE WHEN FreeStockQuantity <= 0 AND AnalysisCode19 > 0
      THEN AnalysisCode19 ELSE FreeStockQuantity
 END) AS Quantity,
```

Possibly the simplest method is to just add `CASE` conditions:

```
(CASE WHEN FreeStockQuantity <= 0 AND AnalysisCode19 > 0 AND AnalysisCode19 <= 30
      THEN AnalysisCode19
      WHEN (FreeStockQuantity > 0 OR AnalysisCode19 <= 0 OR AnalysisCode19 IS NULL) AND FreeStockQuantity <= 30
      THEN FreeStockQuantity
      ELSE 30
 END)
```

The second method uses `CROSS APPLY` in the `FROM` clause;

```
SELECT . . .
       (CASE WHEN raw_quantity < 30 THEN raw_quantity ELSE 30 END)
FROM . . . CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN FreeStockQuantity <= 0 AND AnalysisCode19 > 0
                   THEN AnalysisCode19 ELSE FreeStockQuantity
              END)
     ) v(raw_quantity)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when cwq.CalcQuantity>30 then 30 else cwq.CalcQuantity as Quantity
FROM
  (SELECT CASE WHEN (FreeStockQuantity <= 0 AND AnalysisCode19 is NOT NULL) 
               THEN AnalysisCode19 ELSE FreeStockQuantity END CalcQuantity) cwq
```